# Does a Canadian citizen who is a US permanent resident need a passport to enter Canada?

Tags: passports, canadian-citizens, us-residents

My dad was born in Canada and has been a permanent resident of the US for about 50 years (not a US citizen -- he's lazy). I don't think he has returned to Canada once since he started living in the US.

He is planning a trip to Canada and we are wondering if he needs a passport or if his Green Card is sufficient to exit/enter the US.

If he does need a passport, how can he obtain a passport while living outside the country? If it's a requirement that he be physically present in the country to apply for and obtain a passport, that will likely preclude the possibility of him going altogether?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this page from the Canadian government](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=593&top=16) showing a green card is sufficient for an U.S. permanent resident to enter Canada *at the land border*. But for traveling by air a passport is required.

Usually, people living outside their country of citizenship can get passport issued by consular posts of their country of citizenships. However [Canadian consulates in the US do *not* provide passport services](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/passport/apply/new/apply-how.asp). Instead it appears he can apply for a new passport from the US *by mail* -- see previous link.

Comment: It is  worth adding that if a Canadian citizen traveling by air to Canada, they must fly with a Canadian passport. They can not use a passport issued by any other country.

Comment: The process for applying for a Canadian passport by mail is a bit arcane (though it's better than it used to be);  in particular, one has to find a "guarantor" and two "references", each of which has a laundry-list of requirements.  If you do need guidance on this, it might be worth posting a separate question on our sister site [expats.stackexchange.com](http://expats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk that is incorrect.  A dual citizen of the US and Canada can fly to Canada with a US passport.  This is possible because US citizens do not require eTA authorization.  But anyway this is not relevant to the present question because the traveler is not a dual citizen of the US or any other country.  The only passport he could fly with is a Canadian passport because the only country he's a  citizen of is Canada.

Comment: Worth to add: if OP has a NEXUS Card, that's OK on ist own by air too